# How to match across 2 data frames IDs and run operations in R loop?

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames, the sampling ("samp") and the coordinates ("coor").

The "samp" data frame:

```
Plot    X   Y   H   L
1   6.4 0.6 3.654   0.023
1   19.1    9.3 4.998   0.023
1   2.4 4.2 5.568   0.024
1   16.1    16.7    5.32    0.074
1   10.8    15.8    6.58    0.026
1   1   16  4.968   0.023
1   9.4 12.4    6.804   0.078
2   3.6 0.4 4.3 0.038
3   12.2    19.9    7.29    0.028
3   2   18.2    7.752   0.028
3   6.5 19.9    7.2 0.028
3   3.7 13.8    5.88    0.042
3   4.9 10.3    9.234   0.061
3   3.7 13.8    5.88    0.042
3   4.9 10.3    9.234   0.061
4   16.3    2.4 5.18    0.02
4   15.7    9.8 10.92   0.096
4   6   12.6    6.96    0.16
5   19.4    16.4    8.2 0.092
10  4.8 5.16    7.38    1.08
11  14.7    16.2    16.44   0.89
11  19  19  10.2    0.047
12  10.8    2.7 19.227  1.2
14  0.6 6.4 12.792  0.108
14  4.6 1.9 12.3    0.122
15  12.2    18  9.6 0.034
16  13  18.3    4.55    0.021
```

The "coor" data frame:

```
Plot    X   Y
1   356154.007  501363.546
2   356154.797  501345.977
3   356174.697  501336.114
4   356226.469  501336.816
5   356255.24   501352.714
10  356529.313  501292.4
11  356334.895  501320.725
12  356593.271  501255.297
14  356350.029  501314.385
15  356358.81   501285.955
16  356637.29   501227.297
17  356652.157  501263.238
18  356691.68   501262.403
19  356755.386  501242.501
20  356813.735  501210.59
22  356980.118  501178.974
23  357044.996  501168.859
24  357133.365  501158.418
25  357146.781  501158.866
26  357172.485  501161.646
```

I wish to run "for loop" function to register the "samp" data frame with the GPS coordinates from the "coor" data frame -- e.g. the "new_x" variable is the sum output of "X" from the "samp" and the "coor" , under the same "Plot" IDs.

This is what i tried but not working.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(samp)){

    if (samp$Plot[i]==coor$Plot[i]){

        (samp$new_x[i]<-(coor$X[i] + samp$X[i]))

}           else (samp$new_x[i]<-samp$X[i])

}
```

The final output i wish to have is with a proper coordinate variable ("new_x") created onto the "samp" data frame. It should looks like this:

```
Plot    X   Y   H   L   new_x
1   6.4 0.6 3.654   0.023   356160.407
1   19.1    9.3 4.998   0.023   356173.107
1   2.4 4.2 5.568   0.024   356156.407
1   16.1    16.7    5.32    0.074   356170.107
1   10.8    15.8    6.58    0.026   356164.807
1   1   16  4.968   0.023   356155.007
1   9.4 12.4    6.804   0.078   356163.407
2   3.6 0.4 4.3 0.038   356158.397
3   12.2    19.9    7.29    0.028   356186.897
3   2   18.2    7.752   0.028   356176.697
3   6.5 19.9    7.2 0.028   356181.197
3   3.7 13.8    5.88    0.042   356178.397
3   4.9 10.3    9.234   0.061   356179.597
3   3.7 13.8    5.88    0.042   356178.397
3   4.9 10.3    9.234   0.061   356179.597
4   16.3    2.4 5.18    0.02    356242.769
4   15.7    9.8 10.92   0.096   356242.169
4   6   12.6    6.96    0.16    356232.469
5   19.4    16.4    8.2 0.092   356274.64
10  4.8 5.16    7.38    1.08    356534.113
11  14.7    16.2    16.44   0.89    356349.595
11  19  19  10.2    0.047   356353.895
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's helpful to say what you mean by "not working." Do you get an error? Or does the output look wrong?

Comment: No error message returned, however the output of the "new_x" is identically same as the "X" in the "samp" data frame. I guess only the "else (samp$new_x[i]<-samp$X[i])" line is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You could `merge` the two datasets and create a new column by summing the `X.x` and `X.y` variables.

```
res <- transform(merge(samp, coor, by='Plot'), new_x=X.x+X.y)[,-c(6:7)]
colnames(res) <- colnames(out) #`out` is the expected result showed
all.equal(res[1:22,], out, check.attributes=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```